# Correct title given to the highest authority of described organization

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I am wondering what the right title is of the highest authority of the organization that have these specifications:

- It's an organization that was required by the government office to show 1 million of the country's currency from the organization's bank account plus assets (house, vehicles, etc)
- The organization is registered at Securities and Exchange Commission, Department of Trade and Industry and Intellectual Property Office

As of the moment, the highest authority of the organization has the title "President" where I'm not really sure if it is the right title. I've been thinking that the "President" title is only given to a system of organization where the member elect the person. As far as I know, there is no election in the organization I have described above. I'm actually inclining to "Executive Director" as the right title to be given to the highest authority given to the the organization I have described above, but I am not entirely sure.

This is the sole reason why I am asking about this. Can somebody kindly clear what is the appropriate title that is given to the highest authority of such organization I described above?

Edit: I would not really say it is a company but more of an organization

Comment: I think you can call yourself whatever you want, but many companies use the term CEO- Chief Executive Officer.

Comment: Would Führer go down well? WP has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_title) full of titles.

Comment: coleopterist's Wikipedia link includes _president_, and the language there would dispel the notion that all presidents are elected.

Comment: The company I work for has a President who is appointed by the board, and a rather bewildering number of Vice-Presidents. But then it's an American company. [Aleks G](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/84678/18696) is more in tune with UK practice. [Welcome @AleksG!]

Comment: I can't speak for other countries, but in the U.S., the head of any organization if often called the "president". Heads of companies are routinely called "president" and they are not elected, they get that position either because they originally started the company, or because they were appointed by a board. "Executive director" is a title usually given to someone who manages an organization on a day-to-day basis but who is not the ultimate authority. An executive director is usually appointed by some board or committee. In the last few decades we have seen the title ...

Comment: ... "chief executive officer" as someone above the president. My personal suspician is that this was invented just so they could give more people prestigious titles, partly for their own egos and partly to impress the customers. A client may well prefer to negotiate with the "president" than with the "marketing director", it gives the sense that agreements reached are final, etc.

Comment: Just to be clear - it is an organization, not really a company. That is why I am not sure if "President" is the right title to be given to the highest authority. Either way, thanks guys for your input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While *executive director* is a high authority, it may not be the highest possible one; and there may be more than one *executive director* in an organisation.

I'm inclined to say *CEO* (*Chief Executive Officer*) or *Chairman of the Board* (if the organisation has a formal board of directors).

Comment: Thanks! Will inform my friends and colleagues in the organization in our upcoming meeting :)